# Attempting Simple QPushButton Background color changing

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I need help creating a simple 'blinking' effect by changing the background color of a Q push button. I thought if I can change the background color between 2 colors fast enough, I can generate this blinking effect. However, while I can set the background color to one color, I cant figure out how to change between the 2 colors fast. I tried using loops, but my output GUI only stays with one color. Im a beginner to this type of stuff so perhaps im missing a simple solution.

I have all the necessary packages and everything, so I only included the button part that deals with the background colors for simplicity, this is where I believe my issue is in.

```
self.powerup_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

count = 0

while count < 100:


   self.powerup_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: none")
   count = count + 1

   self.powerup_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
   count = count + 1
```

I thought the while loop would make the button switch between the 2 colors, creating the blink effect I would like but I was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using self.powerup_button.repaint() or self.powerup_button.update() after you change its colour?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.flag = True

        self.powerup_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.powerup_button)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_background)
        timer.start()  

    def update_background(self):
        if self.flag:
            self.powerup_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: none;")
        else:
            self.powerup_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")  
        self.flag = not self.flag            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! this works great. I cant seem to attach it to my Designer generated file thoug, it has no errors but it wont show the blinking, im not sure why.